# How to get User Location using IP Address + Geo Location in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm creating a website in ASP.NET (Framework 4.0).

On this site I need to automatically want to Bind city in dropdownlist based on the user's location.

Can I get name of user's city based on the IP address of the user ?

Code for dropdownlist

```
public void BindCity()
{
    try
    {
       // ddlCities.DataSource = obj.GetCity();
        DataSet ds = obj.GetCity();
        ddlCities.DataSource = ds;
        ddlCities.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddlCities.DataValueField = "CityId";
        ddlCities.DataBind();
        ddlCities.Items.Insert(0, "Select City");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        //Label1.Text = "Please Select Country";
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "warning", "$('#warning').modal();", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to work with a [Geolocation API](https://www.google.com/#q=geolocation+api) to "map" geo coordinates to some "place" (city, etc.)

Comment: @EdSF I have a question whenever i see a some website it ask for  location for better result . How do they code it , can you elaborate it?

Comment: The first result in the Google search link is a [full example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) to get the first part (geo coordinates) at which point, you will need another API (in the example its Google Maps), to obtain a "place"  (for those coordinates).

Comment: Another option is to again, choose your API that has a database of IP addresses and their locations (_of the IP address_). This means you'll either call their API or obtain the data to store in your database. This doesn't rely on user permission/browser prompt.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this using just the Framework. You need to query some type of whois service for that type of information.